# How to build a elegant customized URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am working on a dashboard page where user will have a multiple choices to select properties and based on the selected properties it will generatea final URL and render.

so let say i have 10 different proprites:

```
ShowImage=true/false
ShowWindow=true/false
ShowAdmin = true/false
ShowAccounts = true/false
.............
..........
...........
```

my URL will be static which will be hitting the produciton so there is no change in terms of HOSTNAME.

so here is what i come-up with:

```
const string URL = "http://www.hostname.com/cont.aspx?id={0}&link={1}&link={2}........"; 
string.Format(URL, "123","aaa123", "123"............);
```

but the problem with the above solution is that, regardless it will generate me a long url whether i select or not...

any optimized solution?

Comment: You have a total of 2,083 characters for a URL, so I don't think that is truly all that long.

Comment: Just send the True Parameters, don't add empty/false/default values.

Comment: You could use a bit field. You would be sending sending all the boolean options in a single field. You'd have to add extra logic to handle it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `StringBuilder` class (`System.Text` namespace):

```
StringBuilder sbUrl = new StringBuilder();

sbUrl.AppendFormat("http://www.hostname.com/cont.aspx?id={0}", 123);

if (ShowImage) {
    sbUrl.AppendFormat("&link1={0}", "aaa123");
}

if (ShowWindow) {    
    sbUrl.AppendFormat("&link2={0}", "aaa123");
}

string url = sbUrl.ToString();
```